# Python 3 reading .csv file properly

Tags: python, csv, python-3.x

I have a .csv file with 6 columns  labeled  longitude, latitude, elevation, segment distance, total distance, and unlabeled column.

we only need to use the data from the elevation column and the segment distance column as we are using this data to calculate calories burned for the route of a bicycle rider.  we want to calculate it for every segment of the trip and output it to a animated graph. i honestly do not know where to start with this as i am just getting into programming.

any ideas or help?

Comment: Welcome. This question is too broad for a sensible answer. When faced with a seemingly impossible problem, try to break it down into reasonable chunks. Start by parsing the CSV with the Python [`csv` module](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/csv.html), then move on to doing the calculations. You'll get there if you do it step by step.

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend you take a look into the csv module in the python lib: http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

```
>>> import csv
>>> with open('eggs.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
...     spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')
...     for row in spamreader:
...         print ', '.join(row)
Spam, Spam, Spam, Spam, Spam, Baked Beans
Spam, Lovely Spam, Wonderful Spam
```

If you need concrete examples you should post a few lines of your csv file